# Spark master isn't accessible remotely when cluster is published using docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, apache-spark, swarm

I have a Spark cluster running on a remote server, that is set up using a docker-compose.yml on top of bitnami's Spark image.
When I spin up the containers using `docker-compose up`, I can submit jobs to the remote cluster from my machine using the `spark://host-ip:port`, and everything works fine. However, if I use `docker stack deploy` to deploy the spark cluster as a swarm service, I get connection refused when I try to submit to the remote cluster.

Here's my partial `docker-compose.yml` file, which includes the parts that seem relevant to the problem.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  spark:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.2.0
    ports:
      - 10001:8080
      - 10000:7077

  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.2.0
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
```

The Spark UI port mapping works fine in either method; I can access the Spark UI both when deployed as a stack and when I've started it using `docker-compose up`. The workers also connect to the master in both scenarios.

By the way, I haven't defined any network in the docker-compose file, and it's using the default network in both cases.